# Get relative position of mouse in a window in x11

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I need to get the relative position of mouse pointer in the window in which it is clicked, i've coded to capture the click event, but when i use this code

```
result = XQueryPointer(disp, XRootWindow(disp,0),&win, &win, &root_x, &root_y, &win_x, &win_y, &mask_return);
```

it shows the global position of mouse when printing win_x and win_y

only window i have is "win" the display is "disp"

Comment: Found out
evt.xbutton.x and evt.xbutton.y returns window relative mouse co ordinates

Comment: You are passing the root window to `XQueryPointer`, why do you expect it will give you mouse position relative to some other window? The third and the fourth argument are not your window, they are __results__ of `XQueryPointer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out evt.xbutton.x and evt.xbutton.y returns window relative mouse co ordinates